# How to Include JS file to all JSP pages at run time?

Tags: java, jsp

I need to load a common JS file  while loading all JSP pages in my project.Its a third party statistics tracking JS SDK .I need to integrated with my project ,Which contains mixed html and JSP pages.Its difficult to add script tag in all pages mannualy. 
Any suggession to do it and thanks in advance.

Comment: your jsps include some common file like header or footer etc??

Comment: my question is diffrent

Comment: as per selvakumar said, try to include that js file in existing js file which you used in all files.

Comment: Its should be work as a SDK .i need to make a commomn doc to include it to all projets.

Comment: can i do it through filter class or by overriding any class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have used any technologies like tiles or common jsp pages like header footer then it will be one place you need to add. Otherwise no other way  you will have to include the script tag in all Jsp pages if you have individual pages.

OR If you have any script file already included in all the file you include your js file in that JS file

Comment: Nice idea to include js file in existing js.

Comment: can i do it through filter class by overriding any class ?

Comment: by using this answer of the link we can include  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145914/including-a-js-file-within-a-js-file

Comment: You may go through it. It may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736328/looking-for-an-example-for-inserting-content-into-the-response-using-a-servlet-f 
where they have examples for inserting content in servlet filter at run time

Answer (score 1):

by using normal script method you can attach

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: this will add to current jsp only.. he needs to add to all JSPs

Comment: create on header.jsp file, in their you put your scripts and include that file in all jsp page.

Comment: Its dificult to me ,to do the same  i need to add script to all my pages.I need to integrate same with more projects

Comment: In every project try to have one header and footer file. then whatever change you want to do, you can easily access entire website by using single file.

Answer (score 0):

Create your header file with script tag and more other common tags. Than include header into your page using:

```
<%@include file="header.jsp">
```

You can get more information about include [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/include_directive.htm).

Comment: thank you for reply .it can't solve my problem.It recomend to include every pages.I am searching a solution without updating JSP files

Comment: can i do it through filter class or by overriding any class ?

Comment: In theory yes you can overwrite the response header with filter using i.e. a RequestDispatcher , but I dont have environment to test it.