# Including JS file in JS code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement of including a .js file (more jQuery code) at a run time in a currently working jQuery script. For example, if my page gets authenticated, then I want to include a particular script file. I want to do this in ASP.Net MVC.

Is there a way to do this? If so, what path do I give when calling that file?

I googled `$.getScript('file_path');` but my page is getting refreshed in a loop, I don't why! Maybe I'm doing something wrong in path.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: have a look at require js.  http://requirejs.org/

Comment: `$.getScript()` is exactly what you need. We can't help you with the refreshing problem without seeing your code, though.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Can you help me with the path which I should provide in it. Like, I've my js file in "Scripts" folder in solution explorer, say content.js, and I want to call it in $.getScript();, what path should I give?
like - "~/Scripts/content.js" or something else?

Comment: You can't use `~` in a JS code directly, as it's a MVC construct. You need to use a relative path, eg `$.getScript('/basefolder/foo.js');`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan

I've tried the above thing as below : 

`xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
 if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
  $.getScript(xhr.responseText);
 } else if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status == 403) {
  location.href = '/Home/Auth';
 }
};`

while "xhr.responseText" would reply as "/Scripts/content.js"

but no success, I think path is being a issue.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you! Got my code working now.. path set to basefolder i.e, "../../js/foo.js".

Comment: Glad you got it working. I added an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added correct path and it worked with "$.getScript();"

Answer (score 0):

Try this **[Including a .js file within a .js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145914/including-a-js-file-within-a-js-file)**

Basically, create script tag, append it so that it is read before the one that requires it & load the needed .js

Answer (score 0):

```
//Load JS files as following

["../common/howler.min.js","js/min.js"].forEach(function (src) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = src;
    script.async = false;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.getScript()` is exactly what you should use for this.

> I want to call it in $.getScript();, what path should I give? like - "~/Scripts/content.js" or something else?

The issue there is because the tilde character (`~`) is an ASP.Net MVC construct which will not work in Javascript. For JS you need to use a relative path, for example:

```
$.getScript('/basefolder/foo.js');
```